# horizontal scrollbar with css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have the following html code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            div{border:solid 1px;}
            .cool{width:400px;height:102px; overflow:auto;}
            .cool div{width:100px;height:100px;}
        </style>
        <div class="cool">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/H3UWg/)

It is giving a vertical scrollbar but i want horizontal .How can i get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/H3UWg/1/

Added `display: inline-block` to `.cool div` and `white-space: nowrap` to `.cool`

Comment: When i write hello to the first .cool div then the structure looks ugly

Answer (score 1):

If you want the divs to stay inline rather than block, there are a few ways. Personally, I hate `float:left`.

Try this:

```
    .cool{width:400px;height:122px; overflow:auto;white-space:nowrap;}
    .cool div { width:100px;height:100px;display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline; }
```

Note: The `zoom:1;*display:inline;` business is an IE7 or less hack

http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/tPb2v/

Comment: Is there no other way which is loved by you

Comment: I forgot to paste my changes to .cool. See my updated answer.

Comment: Why have you added zoom and *display

Comment: The hack is incorrect since if the div's do becomes `display: inline` then the width and height won't affect the element, which is an unwanted behavior.
+ `zoom: 1` doesn't solve all IE problems :)

Comment: @iMoses `*display:inline` will be ignored by browsers other than IE7 or less, who don't support inline-block. So good browsers will see display:inline-block, and crappy old IE versions will see display:inline. Said crappy old versions will let you set width and height on inline elements, so long as you do something to force setLayout (hence, zoom:1) ;)

Comment: Fair enough. Haven't coded for quirks mode in quite a while. Arr.. IE6. God forbid!

Btw, IE7 is fine as long as you are using a DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you are hoping for infact I think the other answer are better! But as an alternative, you could have a containing div inside .cool that has a predefined width.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/alexkey/Vs5Wk/